# How do I swap two arraylist in JAVA?

Tags: java, arraylist

There are two ArrayList e.g.`list1 = {1,2,3}`  and `list2 = {7,6,4,2}` How to can swap these two list. So the result will be `list1 = {7,6,4,2}` and `list2 = {1,2,3}`
Can I implement like this:

```
public void swapList(ArrayList<Integer> list1, ArrayList<Integer> list2){
    ArrayList<Integer> tmpList = list1;
    list1 = list2;
    list2 = tmpList;
}
```

Comment: +1 You asked below the follow-up question "Is there any less memory cost way to solve this problem? Since I may have much element in my list."  Consider asking that as a separate StackOverflow question.  Show how you're using this method and ask that question.  I think it's a really good one.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No you can't implement it like that. Same with arrays. Pass-reference-by-value problem, like the others explained already.

If you want the lists to swap their *content*, then you have to clear and copy:

```
public static void swapList(List<Integer> list1, List<Integer> list2){
    List<Integer> tmpList = new ArrayList<Integer>(list1);
    list1.clear();
    list1.addAll(list2);
    list2.clear();
    list2.addAll(tmpList);
}
```

---

Some additional thoughts:

```
List<Integer> list1 = getList1Magic();
List<Integer> list2 = getList2Magic();

if (isSwapReferences()) {
  // this does not affect the actual lists
  List<Integer> temp = list2;
  list2 = list1;
  list1 = temp;
} else if (isSwapListContent()) {
  // this modifies the lists
  swapList(list1, list2);  // method from above
}
```

The swap strategy depends on your requirements. First block has a local effect, second block a global one.

Comment: This is precise solution, customization can also be made for null values of the arguments (list1 and list2)

Comment: Keep in mind that this is much slower. If you can, you should swap just the references.

Comment: It makes my head hurt to think about all the memory and CPU being wasted here.

Comment: This is *Part 1: How To Do It*. *Part 2: How To Avoid It* is sold separately ;)

Comment: Is there any less memory cost way to solve this problem? Since I may have much element in my list.

Comment: Sure: don't use a method to swap. Do it, where you have defined your variables (local variables or members) and swap the references there. If you want to swap in a method, than it gets expensive. *And*: the swapped content effects *all* other variables, that hold references to the lists. They see the swapped content too. So it depends on your requirement.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your solution is that Java is a **pass-by-value** language. So any change to `list1` and `list2` variables will not have an effect outside the method, but if this is not in a method, then it's ok.

Two more things:

1. You probably meant `list2 = tmpList;`, not `list2 = list1;`.
2. You cannot use generic with primitives, should be `List<Integer>`.

Comment: Not entirely, see the other two answers. Still you are closest to the correct answer.

Comment: The problem is that Java is *not* pass-by-reference.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it in a function because of [Java is pass by value only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference).
And you can't create a List of int, you can create a List of Integer.

You can try this to verify that it does not work:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
    List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6);
    System.out.println(list1); //prints 1, 2, 3
    swapList(list1, list2);
    System.out.println(list1); //prints 1, 2, 3
}

public static void swapList(List<Integer> list1, List<Integer> list2){
    List<Integer> tmpList = list1;
    list1 = list2;
    list2 = tmpList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Minor correction in your approach:

```
    ArrayList<Integer> tmpList = list1;
    list1 = list2;
    list2 = tmpList;
```

But you can not do this in a method the way you are doing.

Answer (score -3):

You can use the swap method from Collections:

```
Collections.swap(Integer, list1, list2);
```

Comment: [this is now how swap works](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html)